# Oracle WebLogic EAR Extensions facet not being added to my web service

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic

I am trying to generate a top down SOAP web service project in eclipse kepler.

I am publishing my service to a locally deployed weblogic 12c server.

It's just the stub WSDL file that eclipse can generate for you at the moment. The only thing I am changing is the url to point to localhost.

The slider for the for the generation level for the service and client are both set to the start level.

I get the error.

```
    Error with publish task 'WebServicesProjectSplitSourceTask'.
testwebsEAR is missing the Oracle WebLogic EAR Extensions facet.
```

When I cancel out of the builder tool, it has generated the skeleton code for the service.

It creates a halfway generated EAR without the Oracle WebLogic EAR Extensions facet being included.

It also creates a temp file project stub called JSR-109 Web Services, which I assume would have become my web service client had the EAR Extensions been included in the EAR.

I have tried switching to a new workspace and combing the project and eclipse settings for any applicable configuration, but can't find anything that seems relevant.

The only thing I was able to find was that was halfway relevant is in ProjectEAR->Properties->Project Facets->Configuration setting there is an option for Minimal configuration option that doesn't have the Oracle Weblogic EAR Extensions facet included. However I can't find a place to set the default to the Default Configuration for Oracle Weblogic Server option which does include the EAR Extensions facet.

**Update:** I have a workaround procedure, I make sure that my service project is in an EAR with the weblogic EAR Extensions facet before I try to make the client/service code from the wsdl file. Which is a reasonable workaround for me.

I am concerned that it is leaving behind a build artifact that I can't get rid of. I still have a project stub called JSR-109 that can't be deleted from eclipse. If I exit eclipse I can delete the associated folder called RemoteSystemsTempFile, but it returns when I reenter eclipse.

My concern is that my project will try to perform a function and associate it with that stub of a project and break.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. I was able to resolve it by going to Project Facets and clicking the Apply button. Also, make sure the appropriate Project Facets are select in the web service.

Comment: I resolved the problem from this way: I went to the EAR and select the "Oracle WebLogic EAR Extensions" Project Facet.